# What is the significance of "The letters are worn beyond recognition"?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Majula, there is an obelisk with an inscription which can be examined to display the total amount of deaths worldwide. Around the back of the obelisk, there is another inscription. If you examine it, you get the following message.

> The letters are worn beyond recognition.

Has anyone figured out what this is about? Is there any way to read the inscription?

Answer (score 10):

Nobody has any idea what this will be used for.

In the text dump of DSII, there is a file called regulation.txt which only contents is

> The letters are worn beyond recognition

leading many people to believe that this will be used in future updates, being that it is a variable pulled from a specific text file unlike any other place in the game.

That being said, on [The Far Fire](http://farfire.darksoulsii.com/pc/) there is section in the information section that contains all of the current patch notes. This section is named 'Regulation' as well, so there may be some type of connection there.

It does seem odd that the patch notes section would be called 'Regulation', as I have never seen them referred to as such although it may just be a translation problem as the souls series is in fact a translated game from a Japanese developer.